# Call Contains with Reflection C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to do a search on DbSet with an array of parameters name and one value. Explain that:

I have a generic repository: `Repository<T>`, where T is a entity.
I need to implement this method: `IEnumerable<T> Find(string[] propertiesName, string value);`

So, with PredicateBuilder, I can do this:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Great, It's I want, But, this has an especific type and I need do it Generic, like this:

```
IEnumerable<T> Find(string[] propertiesName, string value){
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();
    foreach(string s in propertiesName){
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.GetType().GetProperty(s).(call contains)(value);
    }
    return DbSet<T>.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

How can I call (string property).Contains with reflections in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Contains` method via

```
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
```

and then call the method using MethodInfo `Invoke`

```
containsMethod.Invoke(stringValue, new object[] { value } );
```

where `stringValue` is what you get via your `p.GetType().GetProperty(s)`

Greetings!